# Composer stopped working... What is ngmy/l4-dav?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php, packagist

I've been having trouble getting composer to update or install since last Friday. Here is a list of my dependencies for this project:

```
"require": {
    "twilio/sdk": "dev-master",
    "ircmaxell/password-compat": "1.0.*",
    "hautelook/phpass": "dev-master",
    "iron-io/iron_mq": "1.4.8",
    "illuminate/events": "4.1.*",
    "illuminate/queue": "4.1.*",
    "hipchat/hipchat-php": ">=1.0.0",
    "bugsnag/bugsnag": "2.*",
    "nesbot/Carbon": "*",
    "xamin/handlebars.php": "dev-master",
    "suin/php-rss-writer": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "mockery/mockery": "dev-master",
    "itsgoingd/clockwork": "1.5"
}
```

Every time I try running `composer update` or `composer install` it runs forever. When I use the `-vvv` option, it always stalls out at this line:

```
Downloading http://packagist.org/p/ngmy/l4-dav$b3c0c28a9d0d18310fd73ebcacaf0aa8a4e0ee497600ae8a38e909c5fc65bdf5.json
Writing /root/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-ngmy$l4-dav.json into cache
```

I've tried deleting my vendor directory and lock file and .composer cache multiple times to no avail.

I have no clue what this repo even is. It's not a dependency of any of the packages I'm using that I can see. It looks like https://packagist.org/packages/ngmy/l4-dav has only gotten 7 installs this month. On Packagist it says that it replaces `phpseclib/phpseclib` ..no idea what that means...

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same issue and got message with:

```
phpseclib/phpseclib
```

My problem was a mispelled version of one package. So, try to go through package names/versions and see if you made any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Composer (`composer self-update`) fixed this for me!